# Site OK on computer but not in smartphone

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, laravel-8

My site appears correctly on computer screens, but not on smartphones.

[image]

Like you can see, the main title (Phytothérapie) is cut and and the three buttons are not centered.

My code :

```
<div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h1 class="mg-md h1-welcome-to-style tc-black">Bienvenue à la</h1>
              <h1 class="mg-md h1-bloc-0-style tc-black"><span style="font-size: 2rem !important;">FACULTÉ DE PHARMACIE DE L'ULB</span></h1>
              <h1 class="mg-sm tc-black h1-3-style"><span style="font-size: 70px !important;">PHYTOTHÉRAPIE</span></h1>
              <h2 class="mg-md tc-black h2-1-style"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and for the 3 blocks :

```
<div class="phyto-container" onclick="location.href='{{$route}}';">
<div class="phyto-front" style="background-image: url({{$bgImage}})">
  <div class="phyto-inner">
    <p>{{ $titleFront }}</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="phyto-back">
  <div class="phyto-inner">
    <div>
      @foreach($paragraphs as $p)
        <p style="font-size: 1.1rem;margin-top:-10px !important; margin-left:-1px !important;">{{ $p }}</p>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The URL of the site is https://overlap.ulb.be/public/

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2  align-self-center"> Repeated 2 times in rendered page. Press f12 to see page errors. There are lot of errors and warnings.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I removed the double lines, it's better, thank you.  I still have to center the button when I am in a little screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried margin-right: 10px; on the title?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I change 70px by 40px, that's OK for the title.  I stil lhave some problems with the 3 buttons.

Comment: Check out 'media querys' for css

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css add this:

```
#unsets {
width: unset !important;
position: unset !important;
padding: unset !important;
margin: 10px;
}
```

and add to all of this divs above id:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 align-self-center" id="unsets">
```

Refresh page or clean cache to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your site responsive,  you can either use frameworks, columns, rows, containers, or media screens.